# mysql trigger - how to insert data into one table that comes from other table with some calculation performed before

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have some idea that not sure if its doable in MySQL.

I have two tables:

1. contains 'from_date', 'to_date'
2. contains 'period' (number of dates between those two dates)

Is it possible to create trigger that each time new dates will be inserted into 1st table in the second table new row populated inserting DATEDIFF() between those two dates into Period?

Comment: Yes. This can be done with an `AFTER` trigger quite easily. The trigger can be written in a manner similar to stored procedures, meaning that you can perform pre-processing of the data before inserting into the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger can be written as follows

```
DELIMITER $$
    
    CREATE TRIGGER dayscount

    AFTER INSERT ON dates 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO Numberofdays(num_days)
       VALUES(DATEDIFF(NEW.todate , NEW.fromdate));
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
    
    INSERT INTO dates VALUES('21/04/01','21/04/29');
```